# no default constructor and automatic property, how come it still compiles

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I'm new to C#, just a question on default constructor and automatic properties. Based on a question on stackoverflow:
[How can I set the value of auto property backing fields in a struct constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522280/how-can-i-set-the-value-of-auto-property-backing-fields-in-a-struct-constructor)

so we have the following struct

```
public struct SomeStruct
{
   public SomeStruct(String stringProperty, Int32 intProperty)
   {
      this.StringProperty = stringProperty;
      this.IntProperty = intProperty;
   }
   public String StringProperty { get; set; }
   public Int32 IntProperty { get; set; }
}
```

but how come it compiles fine to me without calling the default constructor by `:this()`?
Another question is why does the same rule not apply to classes? can you have an automatic property without a default constructor?

Comment: Structs **always** have a default constructor.

Comment: I might be wrong, but IIRC there were older versions of C# where it *wouldn't* compile unless you added `: this()`. But... since assigning to an auto-prop clearly does assign to the field, IIRC it now lets you. Trying to find when/if this changed. Citation - here's a blog talking about this where it **doesn't** work: https://techiesimon.com/2014/01/16/autoproperties-structs-and-constructors-c-wishes-part-3/ - edit, it was C# 6 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/420441/23354

Comment: What are you trying to do? Prevent the caller from creating invalid values? Or preventing the creation of default values?  Structs are value types so they always have a non-null default value and default constructor. Check [Using Structs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-structs) in the C# Programming Guide

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos   can you check the original question in my post to see why the original author did receive a compile error

Comment: as a side note: mutable structs are a terrible idea; you would be **much** better off with `public readonly struct SomeStruct { public string StringProperty {get;} public int Int32Property {get;} public SomeStruct(string stringProperty, int int32Property) { StringProperty = stringProperty; Int32Property = int32Property; }}`

Comment: @slowjams post the relevant information in *your* question. That's a 10 year old question anyway, that refers to a different problem that only occured back then. It's not about the lack of a default constructor. It's about how it was called bakc then. That's not what you asked in your question though - you asked why this code complies : Because it's valid code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately, structs have strict rules on definite assignment before they can be touched as an entire value (necessary for `this` access); before C# 6, the compiler didn't consider auto-properties in constructors as part of definite assignment, so access to call the property setter was considered invalid. Since C# 6, it does (consider auto-properties as part of definite assignment in struct constructors), so the code as shown is now valid.

Because it is valid (with any recent compiler, **even if** you set the language level earlier than C# 6), it compiles.

Note, however, that this **only** applies inside constructors. The following remains invalid (although it would work with naked fields):

```cs
SomeStruct x;
x.StringProperty = "abc"; // CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable x
x.IntProperty = 123;
SomeMethod(x);
```