# Why do I need to call the default constructor for `struct` with auto properties

Tags: c#, struct, backing-field

This won't compile

```
public struct Matrix 
{
    readonly double[] elems;
    public Matrix(int rows, int cols) 
    {
        this.elems=new double[rows*cols];
        this.Rows=rows;
        this.Columns=cols;
    }
    public int Rows { get; private set; }
    public int Columns { get; private set; }
}
```

but this does:

```
public struct Matrix 
{
    readonly double[] elems;
    public Matrix(int rows, int cols) : this()
    {
        this.elems=new double[rows*cols];
        this.Rows=rows;
        this.Columns=cols;
    }
    public int Rows { get; private set; }
    public int Columns { get; private set; }
}
```

Why is that?

The compile time error is

> error CS0188: The 'this' object cannot be used before all of its fields are assigned to

and

> error CS0843: Backing field for automatically implemented property 'SO_MMul.Matrix.Columns' must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller. Consider calling the default constructor from a constructor initializer.

Doesn't the parameterized constructor call the default constructor anyway?

Comment: In particular, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7670809/2642204) explains the issue explicitly.

Comment: The parameterized constructor never calls `this()` by default. In class types, it calls `base()` by default. In structs, `base()` is meaningless (`object` is not applicable until the struct is boxed), so in any case you have to say `this()` explicitly.