# Translate C# Ctor to Vb.Net equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, constructor, code-translation

I have taken this struct definition from the **[Windows API CodePack](https://github.com/aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1/blob/24c911473333d9d502379423f91c237031aed631/source/WindowsAPICodePack/Shell/Common/IconReference.cs)**:

```
public struct IconReference
{
    //...

    public IconReference(string moduleName, int resourceId)
        : this()
    {
        //...
    }

    public IconReference(string refPath)
        : this()
    {
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

The problem is I don't understand how to translate those kind of constructors to Vb.Net.

What is exactlly the meaning of that `: this()`?

When I use an online code translator, it translates it as `Me.New()`, however, this fails at compilation because that struct does not have a parameterless ctor.

Comment: There is no purpose to it, a struct cannot have a default constructor.  Just omit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this()` in C# calls the parameterless constructor. Since you don't have a parameterless constructor in C# (and structs can't even contain "explicit parameterless constructors"), you can omit the `this()`.

And so for the VB.NET code. You can omit the `Me.New()` code.

Comment: Yes a default constructor can be specified in Vb.Net but the MSDN guidelines says it is incorrect to do it, I'm not sure why the WindowsAPICodePack guys did that, but if I can omit it then problem solved, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. VB.NET gave me an error in VS2015, but not in Ideone, so I think they use an outdated compiler. Probably this has been 'fixed' in the lastest version of the VB.NET compiler.

Comment: If you omit the call to the default constructor in C#, you'll hit a [compiler error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513821.aspx), since the class has a automatically implemented property.

Comment: Indeed, not the code OP gave, but as Hans pointed out, that code is incomplete... @sloth

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is needed because IconReference has an "automatically implemented property":

```
  public int ResourceId { get; set; }
```

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/7670854/121309