# automatically implemented properties with struct

Tags: c#, struct

As far as I know when I use automatically implemented properties with struct I should explicitly chain the parameterless constructor (ie the parameterless constructor has to be called before auto implemented properties can be assigned). Now I have the following code that works correctly without chaining `: this()`

```
    public struct Foo
    {
        public int Value { get; private set; }

        public Foo(int value) //: this()
        {
            Value = value;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo f = new Foo(33);
        Console.WriteLine(f.Value);
    }
```

I found similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670780/automatically-implemented-property-in-struct-can-not-be-assigned) where the user was getting a compiler error, and it was suggested to use `: this()` in order to fix the problem. Why my code works without `: this()`? Should we use or not use `: this()`?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an error when using `: this()` ? Could you check which C# version your VS project (or other) is targeting ?

Comment: @ArthurAttout with or without `: this()` I get the same result. I am using VS2017, .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Note that the question&answer you linked to are quite old. The problem this question&answer discussed is not an issue anymore since C# 6... (see the duplicate question i linked to)

Comment: You only need to call `this()` if you want to read value from fields or properties before setting them anything.

Comment: Thanks, I read the other posts and I realized that from C# 6, it is not an issue. Thanks again