# Can a WPF ListBox only display properties from its items?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListBox` that looks like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource journal}" DisplayMemberPath="Title" />
```

When "Title" is a property, e.g:

```
public string Title { get; set; }
```

It displays fine, but if I make `Title` a public field instead, the `ListBox` only displays an empty string. This unfortunately makes it impossible to work with structs, since they don't support properties.

Are there any workarounds to this?

Comment: "This makes it impossible to work with structs" is not true. Look for example at [System.Windows.Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point.aspx). It is a struct with two properties, `X` and `Y` that can be used as source of a binding.

Comment: How can you make a struct with properties? I just get the error *"Backing field for automatically implemented property 'Journal.JournalEntry.Title' must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller. Consider calling the default constructor from a constructor initializer."*

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/420433/1136211).

Comment: @Clemens: Yeah I figured it out :) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WPF Binding engine does not support public fields. You'd better create a ViewModel to show these items (with the appropiate properties) if they are structs.